# Move product attributes inside details tab

Tags: magento2, layout, product-view

Using the Luma theme. On the product page I want to move the "More information" content where it lists the attributes, into the first tab "Details".

I tried to use XML in `catalog_product_view.xml`

This puts it in a tab:

```
<move element="product.attributes" destination="product.info.details" />
```

This makes it go invisible:

```
<move element="product.attributes" destination="product.info.description" />
```

Is there a simple way?

Alternatively, I just want to remove the tabs altogether and make them headings instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make `More information` content section as child block of  `Details`  block, you have already done that using below query

```
<move element="product.attributes" destination="product.info.description" />
```

But now, you have to call this child block as description's template file `attribute.phtml`'s child block,So you need to add  below code

```
<?= $block->getChildhtml() ?>
```

Also, You need to change `div` structure of `More information`  template file.